# Move programmatically path on a vector

Tags: android, imageview, android-vectordrawable

I wanted to programmatically change the position values of a path from a vector drawable. I've seen that it wasn't possible since ressource files cannot be modified after runtime. An animated vector isn't suitable for what I want to do (display a cursor indicating a position while changing acitivities).

So I wanted to ask if you had any Idea of a suitable solution to display a cursor (a point) on an imageview (a map) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use vector morphism: https://lewismcgeary.github.io/posts/animated-vector-drawable-pathMorphing/
or just translate whole vector by X and Y. If you have complex vector maybe you should split it into two vectors.

Comment: I'd like to translate it but the problem is that It has to stay in the same position and keep moving. In all the animations I've seen the path comes back to its original position, plus it needs to stay in the same place even after changing activities.

Comment: I don't understand what means `stay in the same position and keep moving`?

Comment: I have the XY coordinates of the smartphone. I'm displaying the map of the building I am in in an imageview. Now i need to display a point that will move with the coordinates XY. When I'm saying it stays at the same place then moves. I mean that the animation shouldn't come back to its original state and that it should be able to follow the XY coordinates

Comment: So you have image view with one vector drawable which is map and point. So I think you should have two image views or two layers of your vector drawable and translate only layer/view with point.

Comment: If you need to have animation which will stay in position after animation there is attribute `android:fillAfter="true"`